# Spring boot actuator sample not working

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I checked out spring-boot project from:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot

and after running **spring-boot-sample-actuator** with **mvn spring-boot:run** and navigating to `http://localhost:8080/info`

I see:

{version: "@project.version@", artifact: "@project.artifactId@", group: "@project.groupId@", name: "@project.name@"}

It seems that **Automatic property expansion using Maven** (also exlained here http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-application-info-automatic-expansion)
is not working.

What am I missing, how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that the *spring-boot-maven-plugin* tries first to be able to make the developer productive.
In short, when a path/file is both present in target/classes and in the sources or resources (such as *application.properties*), it will delete the contents under *target/classes*.
This is [clearly visible here.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/maven/RunMojo.java#L303)

So as it is deleting the *target/classes/application.properties*, and adding the project resources to the classpath (so adding here *src/main/resources/application.properties*), you can only get the non-filtered file.

Fortunately, you can disable this behaviour by adding this flag to the command line:

*-Drun.addResources=false*

or in the POM plugin configuration

```
<addResources>false</addResources>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's clarified everything!

Comment: Also as a result of this, if you generate a the jar and the run the application by CLI the property expansion works as expected.